# MySQL 1292 Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, sql-timestamp, mysql-error-1292

I am getting this error when I try to insert '2011/03/13 02:53:50.000000000' into a timestamp column.  If I change the 13 to a 15, 14, 12 or 11 it works no problem.  I've also tried changing the /'s to -'s and still no-go.

I've looked through some of the other threads related to this error but none seem to apply.

I'm running version 5.7.9.

Comment: Look at this.It will help you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: The error message is 1292 Incorrect datetime value.

Comment: @CycleGeek, can you please, provide some SQLfiddle snippet to illustrate this?

Comment: @Farside, here's my [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e1f9/1) and it seems to work.  Weird?

Comment: @CycleGeek, I've got v.5.7.9 on my localhost - and I don't see any issues. What's in your "show variables like 'sql_mode';"?

Comment: @Farside, only_full_group_by, strict_trans_tables, no_zero_in_date, error_for_division_by_zero, no_auto_create_user, no_engine_substitution.  Also, I changed it the column to datetime(6), and it worked?!  But it's still bugging me!

Comment: its simple just go to accounts on auth with Heidesql not navicat only headesql u can config it easy data time update

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out...

The problem is that '2011-03-13 02:53:50' is illegal because of daylight saving time switch between 2 and 3 AM, so all time values between 2 and 3 am on any DST introduction day are invalid. Same for '2016-03-13 02:32:21', etc.

Change the system timezone to the one that does not use DST and you should be fine.

Comment: __@nik thanks for this__. I had not considered that the box I provisioned was stuck in EDT. Importing many thousands of records with timestamps and couldn't see anything wrong with the MySQL setup causing it to reject seemingly random values.

Answer (score 6):

You need to try this:

```
STR_TO_DATE( '2011/03/13 02:53:50', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s')
```

or else you have to insert the dates using the dash seperator **(-)** like

```
'2011-03-13 02:53:50'
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5926/1)**

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure what the issue is/was, maybe a combination of CentOS and MySQL versions.  I changed the column to datatime(6) instead of timestamp(6) and I was able to import all my data successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use some [str conversions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) before inserting. Or to prepare the data in the proper format, before making the query to MySQL.

The microseconds format is also wrong. [MySQL documentation clearly states this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> A DATETIME or TIMESTAMP value can include a *trailing fractional seconds part* in up to microseconds **(6 digits)** precision.

---

UPDATE: on my localhost I've got the same version of MySQL, and it works.
Tryed to execute conversion

```
select str_to_date("2011-03-13 02:53:50.000000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f") as `t`
```

and gotten:

```
+----------------------------+
| t                          |
+----------------------------+
| 2011-03-13 02:53:50.000000 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b758/1/0), that confirms the thing on other version of MySQL.

I run out of ideas, I think the issue is connected to the "local glitch" in Table structure or specific version of MySQL+OS.

Comment: Then why, when I change the day to 15, 14, 12 or 11 does it work?  I've also tried using 6 digits as well with no luck.

Comment: @CycleGeek, do you get the correct conversions when the date is inserted, and then you try to select it back? I feel something is wrong with the string conversion itself

Comment: Yes if I insert '2011-03-12 02:53:50.000000' or '2011/03/12 02:53:50.000000' it works fine.  A select shows a matching date.  The 13 for some reason isn't working?

Comment: @CycleGeek, try to use other formats, it's easy. Replace slashes with dashes, or use the STR_TO_DATE conversions. This will help in your case. The range for TIMESTAMP values is '1970-01-01 00:00:01.000000' to '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999'. The fractional part should always be separated from the rest of the time by a decimal point

Comment: @CycleGeek, I checked on my end, also tryed SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b758/1/0) , it works. Try to dump your DB, and to see what's wrong.

Comment: I tried str_to_date('2011-03-13 02:53:50.000000', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s.%f) and got the same error.  But when I tried str_to_date('2011-03-1**2** 02:53:50.000000', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s.%f) it worked!

Comment: @CycleGeek:- You are providing the format different and the dates different. Just try this: str_to_date('2011/03/13 02:53:50.000000', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s.%f) To be more clear, you are providing the dates using dash(-) and the format is using the (/) formatter

Comment: That was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Maybe because the last number is in fact the month and not the day that's why it fails for number greater than 12 (=december)

Comment: @Delphine, the last number is the day.  15 and 14 work fine.

Comment: @CycleGeek Ok sorry I did not noticed that. Have you tried Farside update ?

Answer (score 0):

1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '2004-10-11 19:08:58.503079+05:30' for column `grideye`.`alerts`.`timestamp` at row 1

if you are getting the above error must try this
**I written,**

```
timestamp = parser.parse(data.get('timestamp'))
```

I tried this and **this worked for me**

```
timestamp = datetime.strptime(data.get('timestamp'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```